# Spring boot/Amazon PostgreSQL RDS connection pool issue

Tags: spring, postgresql, amazon-rds

I am troubleshooting an issue with a Spring Boot app connecting to a PostgreSQL database.  The app runs normally, but under fairly moderate load it will begin to log errors like this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Timeout after 30000ms of waiting for a connection.
```

This is running on an Amazon EC2 instance connecting to a PostgreSQL RDS.  The app is configured like the following:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://[rds_path]:5432/[db name]
spring.datasource.username=[username]
spring.datasource.password=[password]
spring.datasource.max-active=100
```

In the AWS console, I see 60 connections active to the database, but that is across several Spring Boot apps (not all this app).  When I query the database for current activity using pg_stat_activity, I see all but one or 2 connections in an idle state.  It would seem the Spring Boot app is not using all available connections?  Or is somehow leaking connections?  I'm trying to interpret how pg_stat_activity would show so many idle connections and the app still getting connection pool time outs.

Comment: probably firewall issue. are you sure you opened port for your application server?

Comment: Sorry, clarified my post.  Only under some load does the application encounter connection errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Spring is using the Hikari database connection pooling (didn't realize that until after more closely inspecting the stack trace).  Hikari configuration parameters have different names, to set the pool size you use maximum-pool-size.  Updated that and problem solved.

Comment: Hey Mike! Can you please help me with the setup. I am facing same problem here.